# Objects in SpriteKit Game Stopped Colliding after iOS 7.1 update

Tags: ios, collision-detection, sprite-kit, bitmask

Objects in my spriteKit game stopped colliding after the iOS 7.1 update. This includes the bounds of the screen so the character just runs off screen. I'm using a bit mask to detect collisions and handling the collisions in the didBeginContact delegate method. I'll add the code for how I'm adding my SKNodes. Thanks in advance.

```
//main character 
self.girl = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pixelgirl"];
self.girl.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height * 0.2);
[self addChild:self.girl];        
self.girl.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.girl.size.height / 4];
self.girl.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
self.girl.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.girl.physicsBody.mass = 0.02;
self.girl.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.girl.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = girlCategory;
self.girl.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = tallTreeCategory | uglyTreeCategory | shortTreeCategory;

//contact object 
SKSpriteNode *pixelShort = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pixelshort"];
pixelShort.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:pixelShort.size.width / 2]; //2
pixelShort.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
pixelShort.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = uglyTreeCategory;

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

__block BOOL isRotating;

[self performSelector:@selector(moveDog) withObject:Nil afterDelay:.3];

isRotating = NO;

if (!isRotating) {
    SKAction* action0 = [SKAction scaleXTo:1.0 duration:0.05];
    SKAction* action1 = [SKAction scaleXTo:0.1 duration:0.05];
    SKAction* action2 = [SKAction scaleXTo:-0.1 duration:0.05];
    SKAction* action3 = [SKAction scaleXTo:-1.0 duration:0.05];

    SKAction* action = [SKAction sequence:@[action0,action1,action2, action3]];

    [self.girl runAction:action completion:^{
        isRotating = YES;
    }];

    }

}
```

Comment: Dynamic needs to be YES.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I changed them to YES. Also, the sprites dance around the screen when dynamic is YES.

Comment: The weird thing is, contact with the first sprite works fine. It's after the first contact that the sprites just go through each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `scaleXTo:-1.0`. I used the exact same command to mirror one of my sprites and as soon as I did, the little guy stopped responding to ALL contacts. Remove it and all be well again.

Comment: I believe there are other questions/answers regarding this. Also, be sure to set the `showsPhysics` property of your `SKView` to `YES`  It will likely help you visually see the problem cause by the negative scale bug.

Comment: @prototypical - Absolutely. I was never to solve this xTo-1 issue and ended up creating mirror images for my sprites. I praised the genius who created keyboard shortcuts that day!

Comment: YEESSS. Thank you so much. That was it. I never thought that would be the problem. I thought it would be some property of the nodes. TY. Is there an alternative to making the sprite spin?

Comment: Happy to hear that resolved your issue. It drove me NUTS for days! As for spinning your sprite... you could rotate it by changing the zRotation property BUT REMEMBER that zRotation is in radians. 1 radian = 57.3 degrees. You could also attach a short 'repeat forever' animation to your sprite consisting of a couple of frames.